# Styling a child component differently in another component

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I am trying to style my `alert` box (from bootstrap) [which is also a component] slightly different when it shows up in one of my components. For the other places i would like to use its default styling.

I am able to achieve what i want by using:

`encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in my parent component. However i really want to avoid it and learn to do it using best practice.

Can anyone shed some light of how can this be achieved without modifying `encapsulations` ?

In some posts users mention to use `:host` and `::content` css properties but so far i am unable to make any use out of them.

I believe this is a very common scenario and there should be a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/deep/` in the parent like

```
:host /deep/ some-grand-child {
  color: blue;
}
```

to make selectors cross component boundaries without setting `ViewEncapsulation` to `None`.

Comment: Wow - it works! Thanks. I did see people mention `/deep/` but never thought it would work in a CSS selector. I need to study shadow DOM more in depth apparently.

Comment: That's Angular2+ only and only works with `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`. In shadow DOM they were added to Chrome but deprecated (Angular rewrites the selector)